# Drools Rest API - Filtering Rules

Tags: rest, filter, server, drools, kie

i'm using REST API to execute my rules on my kie server.

I have 2 different rules using the same Object and when I call Drool API, it execute the 2 different rules.

But I want to execute ONE specific rule.

Here what I'm using when I call the REST API :

```css
<batch-execution>
    <insert out-identifier="ReturnedSchedule" return-object="true">
        <test.a xmlns="http://test">
            <a>1111111</a>
   <b>0</b>
   <c>            
        </test.a>
    </insert>
    <fire-all-rules/>
</batch-execution>
```

I saw in documentation the parameter agendaFilter with fire-all-rules but it doesn't work.

Any idea to help me ?

Comment: If you need to isolate the rules into groups so one group runs before another you could use the [ruleflow-group](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.23.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_rule_flow) keyword. Might be helpful to post your current rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

if there is multiple conditions and all those things are true and if u want to fire only one then u have to go with **activation-group**.